# Datamart exercise on a Data warehouse

Tags: database, data-science, data-warehouse

This is the text of the exercise:

Let us consider the monitoring of production machines, e.g., in the manufacturing industry. A machine, identified by a unique ID, operates under a given range of temperature, humidity, electric voltage, lubricant level, and other measurement types. Machines are installed with sensors that read the value of measures once a minute.
In case of failures, human operators document the type of problem, and the time needed for repairing the machine (downtime).
A company with several factories will collect the flow of data from sensors and operators and populate a data warehouse for analysis of failures.

The following are some examples of business questions collected during the user interviews.

(a) Number of failures by month and by the factory.

(b) Average downtime by failure type.

(c) Average, minimum, and maximum measurement value by measurement types.

(d) Average lubricant level in 1hour before a failure by machine ID.

Concerning the above business scenario, answer the following questions design a conceptual schema for the data mart to support the business questions.
Your schema should at least be able to satisfy the above mentioned analysis requirements.
You may motivate other suitable attributes for the dimensions.

I think that the solution is a datamart with two fact tables: one for machines and one for failures. I would like to know if there are other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The Dim Machine will be a [conformed dimension](https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/conformed-dimension/) can exist as a single dimension table that relates to multiple fact tables within the same data warehouse, or as identical dimension tables in separate data marts.

In your case, the **Multidimensional Schema** used is **Galaxy Schema** since there are two fact tables **Fact Monitoring** and **Fact Failure** that share the **Dim Machine** between them. It is also called **Fact Constellation Schema**. The schema is viewed as a collection of stars hence the name Galaxy Schema.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to use some tricks to modelling one single fact table?

Comment: @Lara one fact = one business need